# How do I implement Google Maps API V3 Image Map Type?

Tags: google-maps-api

I'm new to the Google Maps API V3 and I am trying to add a set of map tiles via the [image map type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?csw=1#ImageMapTypes). I followed the steps in this [article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-google-maps-api-and-custom-overlays--webdesign-13868), and have had no dramas creating the Tileset. I used GDAL2TILES and the the tilesets looks as expected in the preview apps that are generated with the program.

However I cannot get the tilset to show up in my google maps application. My implementation of the Image map type looks like this below

```
    //The index.html and 'sma_map_1989' folder are in the same directory 
    var smaMapOverlay = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
      getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return 'sma_map_1989' + '/' +zoom+ '/' +coord.x+ '/' + coord.y +'.png';
      },
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
    });
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(smaMapOverlay);
```

Am I missing something here? It's such a simple thing to do in leaflet and Openlayers.

Comment: Are requests being made to your tilesets? do you see any errors in Firebug/developer console of your broswer?

Comment: Yes the requests are being made - I see a lot of errors relating to tiles that are not in the tileset, but at the same time it doesn't draw the tiles that I have in there. I can share the code with you privately if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stack exchange post solved my problem [Google Maps V3 Custom tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596597/google-maps-api-v3-custom-tiles).

My issue was related to the line `map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, maptiler);` which defines a z-index and the MapType to load. So previously I think the tileset was drawing but not displayed as the top most layer.

Answer (score 0):

I use open street map tile, sample

```
 z= zoom  
 x= coord.x  
 y= coord.y

https://tile.openstreetmap.org/10/261/380.png

https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png
```

For tile, you should use ImageMapTypes, 
then use  **map.overlayMapTypes.push(imageMapType);**
or **map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
            0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));**

to add new tile layer over the google base layer.

You can set opacity by :

```
 // for old api

 //map.overlayMapTypes[0].setOpacity(0.25);





   //for 3.28 api  (in 2018)

   map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(0).setOpacity(0.5);
```

[here is my working example jsfiddle, for overlay tile use ImageMapTypes](https://jsfiddle.net/hoogw/dtL147w2/1/)

[sample: use coordMapType instead of ImageMapTypes](https://jsfiddle.net/hoogw/m94qy82z/)